# C# application cannot find .dll reference file while both are in the same folder

Tags: c#, reference, filenotfoundexception

I have add a .dll file as a reference in my winform c# project.

The output is one .exe file and one .dll file.

It works well when I run the .exe file in bin/debug folder .. or any other folder on my own computer.

For running the .exe file in other computers, I simply copy both .exe file and the .dll file in a folder..

I got confused that it works in some computers, but it pops up stop working error in others :

```
Problem signature:
   Problem Event Name:                        CLR20r3
   Problem Signature 01:                       programname.exe
   Problem Signature 02:                       0.0.0.0
   Problem Signature 03:                       4e20a786
   Problem Signature 04:                       mscorlib
   Problem Signature 05:                       2.0.0.0
   Problem Signature 06:                       4d8c1599
   Problem Signature 07:                       f9b
   Problem Signature 08:                       80
   Problem Signature 09:                       System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   OS Version:                                          6.1.7600.2.0.0.16.7
   Locale ID:                                             1033
```

After using exception control, I got this error details:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dllname.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specific modulo could not be found.
```

What's the problem! both files(.exe and .dll) are in the same folder ! It works on some PCs !

Note that required .Net Framework is installed on all computers.

Note that one time I've installed MS Visual Studio 2012 and after that the error message disappeared and the program worked correctly after that !! I don't know what could be the relation between installing VS 2012 and the problem !

Note that the program also works well in PCs with no VS installed !

Thanks any help in advance.

Comment: Are the computers that its working on 64 bit?  What about the ones its not working on?  What architecture did you build against x86,x64,any cpu?

Comment: Was the same version of .Net installed on all the PCs?

Comment: There are some systemwide packages that are installed by visual studio. It is possible that your dll depends on one of these. Try [using the fusion log](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to identify exactly what binding is failing.

Comment: Note the error message "or one of its dependencies".  It sounds like dllname.dll has a dependency on some other library which happens to be present on your PC but not others.

Comment: If it's a matter of installing VS2012 to get it to work it could either mean that the .NET runtime you are targeting isn't installed on the remote machine, OR, some dependency of yours requires the c++ runtime to be installed as well. VS2012 would install that as part of its installation process

Comment: I second @GeorgeMauer's recommendation on the fusion log to check the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After enabling and checking all Fusion Logs.. no file loading failure detected ! ALL files(eg mydll.dll) is loading successfully ! But the FileNotFoundException is on yet ! REALLY got confused ! PLEASE help me to solve this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for comments,

I've used Dependency Walker and found the missing dlls in the system.

so installing VC++ Redistributable 2010 and other things solved the problem.